# Como puedo calcular los dias sabado y domingo entre dos fechas?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de calcular los dias de fin de semana entre dos fechas ingresadas usando el siguente codigo:

```
public int CalcularDias(DateTime fecha, DateTime fin)
    {
        int contador = 0;


        DateTime dtInicio = fecha;
        DateTime dtFin = fin;



        for (int k = dtInicio.Day; k < dtFin.Day;k++)
        {

            while (dtInicio.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dtInicio.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
                dtInicio = dtInicio.AddDays(1);
                contador++;
            }

            dtInicio = dtInicio.AddDays(1);
        }



        return contador;

    }
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando el día de la fecha es mayor a la fecha a comparar me da error de cálculo y estoy tratando de resolver este error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tal vez podrias probar con algo asi:

```
int count = 0;
            while (DateTime.Compare(fechainicio,fechafin)<0)
            {
               if (fechainicio.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday )
               {
                   count++;
                   fechainicio = fechainicio.AddDays(2);
                   continue;
                }else if (fechainicio.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                   count++;
                   fechainicio = fechainicio.AddDays(1);
                   continue;
                }
            
                fechainicio=fechainicio.AddDays(1);
            
               }

               return count;
```

Lo que hago es sumar un dia si es domingo y dos dias si es sabado, tambien si es entre semana se suma solo un dia.

Comment: Este código es incorrecto. Si fechainicio = '15-12-2022' y fechafin ='22-12-2022' El código dice que existe un día de fin de semana cuando en realidad hay 2

Answer (score 2):

Un for sirve para más que recorrer enteros, perfectamente puedes hacer un for de datetimes y recorrer los días.

El while que tienes no entiendo para que lo pusiste, creo que no tiene sentido, debería ser un if

```
public int CalcularDias(DateTime fecha, DateTime fin)
{
    int contador = 0;
    for (DateTime dia = fecha; dia <= fin; dia = dia.AddDays(1))
    {
        if (dia.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dia.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Comment: busque por internet y encontré este método varias veces

Comment: @AndresEdu No entiendo tu comentario